# Open a browser window with html from script

Tags: javascript

Can anyone suggest how to open a browser window with raw html provided by the Javascript that is opening this window? I need to just show a div in a new page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)

URL - URL to navigate

name - Specifies the target attribute or the name of the window. The following values are supported:

_blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
_parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
_self - URL replaces the current page
_top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded


specs: Optional. A comma-separated list of items. The following values are supported:

channelmode=yes|no|1|0  Whether or not to display the window in theater mode. Default is no. IE only
directories=yes|no|1|0  Whether or not to add directory buttons. Default is yes. IE only
fullscreen=yes|no|1|0   Whether or not to display the browser in full-screen mode. Default is no. A window in full-screen mode must also be in theater mode. IE only
height=pixels   The height of the window. Min. value is 100
left=pixels The left position of the window
location=yes|no|1|0 Whether or not to display the address field. Default is yes
menubar=yes|no|1|0  Whether or not to display the menu bar. Default is yes
resizable=yes|no|1|0    Whether or not the window is resizable. Default is yes
scrollbars=yes|no|1|0   Whether or not to display scroll bars. Default is yes
status=yes|no|1|0   Whether or not to add a status bar. Default is yes
titlebar=yes|no|1|0 Whether or not to display the title bar. Ignored unless the calling application is an HTML Application or a trusted dialog box. Default is yes
toolbar=yes|no|1|0  Whether or not to display the browser toolbar. Default is yes
top=pixels  The top position of the window. IE only
width=pixels    The width of the window. Min. value is 100


replace:    Optional.Specifies whether the URL creates a new entry or replaces the current entry in the history list. The following values are supported:
true - URL replaces the current document in the history list
false - URL creates a new entry in the history list
```

read more on [W3Schoools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: Dont worry abt the Downvotes Niko there are too many Eric Cartmans here with Authoritaaahhhh(Down vote button).

Comment: doc for window.open at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open)

Answer (score 3):

```
var newWin = window.open();
newWin.document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
```

This should do it. Bear in mine that since you are using window.open, you might have problems with popup blockers.