# Open link in new window , not in new tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink, href

I am trying to open a link in new window, tried out some codes but they are displaying it in new tab . Any suggestions please...

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in/" target="_blank" >Demo</a>    // this opens in  new tab

 <li onclick="window.open('https://www.google.co.in/')">Demo</li>  // this is also opening in new tab
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546528/html-open-a-url-on-new-target-and-focus

Comment: @anu detailed answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504294/open-a-browser-window-with-html-from-script/17504305#17504305

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
<li onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindow','height:400;width:400;')">Demo</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one :

```
 <li onclick="window.open('http://publichealth.ecareagora.com','mywindow','height:auto;width:auto;')">Demo</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code i hope it solves your issue

Java Script

```
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) 
 { 
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
  return false;
 }
```

In html button

```
onclick="MM_openBrWindow('help1.php','','width=750, height=650,left =530,
 top =230, location=no, menubar=no, status=yes,toolbar=yes,
  scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes')
```